# Rails create form submitting multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails form calling upon the create function in my controller, and I've noticed if i press the submit button multiple times while the page loads, I am able to submit the form multiple times.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  My button is:

`<%= button_to edit_production_path(id:   current_user.default_working_production_id), class: "btn btn-default navbar-btn", :method => :get do %><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span>&nbsp; Production Settings<% end %>`

And my controller is:

```
def create
    @production = Production.new(production_params)
    @production.user = current_user
    @production.user_name = current_user.name

    if @production.save
        redirect_to productions_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice you are using `edit_path`, which should be a put to the `update` action, but you are specifying `:get` as the method.  Are you sure this is going to your `create` action?

In order to prevent double submits you will need to disable with javascript, add this to the button.

```
data: { disable_with: "Submitting..."}
```